# How to I refresh a JSON object, so it is not too long

Tags: angularjs, rest

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HTTPMEssageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING>
```

[image: The last json object.]

I believe my JSON object may be too long.  It has 60 different id's.  I want to delete them all, and start a fresh.  I used angualrjs $http.put to get them there.  I am using angularjs with a ModelSvc. I do not see the id listed in the data.

While bankInfoes/(id) returns the data, but localhost:9001/bankInfoes does not return any data.

This is the angularjs that I use to control the view.

```
timetrackingServices.factory('BankInfoSvc', ['$resource', '$rootScope', 'RootUrlSvc', 'ModelSvc', '$http',

        function ($resource, $rootScope, RootUrlSvc, ModelSvc, $http) {                                              

                 var initializeModel = function (bankInfo) {

                     var bankInfoResource = $resource(RootUrlSvc.rootUrls.bankInfoes + ':bankInfoId', {}, { 

                         query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false} 

                     });

                     bankInfoResource.query(function (data) {

                         var bankInfoes = data;
                         ModelSvc.model.bankInfoes = bankInfoes;

                     });

                 };

                 return {

                     initializeModel: initializeModel

                 };

    }

]);




timetrackingServices.factory('ModelSvc', [
function () {

    var model = {};
    model.company = {};
    model.bankinfoes = {};
    model.printBossResponses = {};
    model.config = {};

    var isCompanyInitialized = function () {
        return !angular.equals({}, model.company)
    };

    var isBankInfoInitialized = function () {
        return !angular.equals({}, model.bankInfo)
    };

    var isPrintBossResponsesInitialized = function () {
        return !angular.equals({}, model.printBossResponse)
    };

    return {
        model: model,
        isCompanyInitialized: isCompanyInitialized,
        isBankInfoInitialized : isBankInfoInitialized,
        isPrintBossResponsesInitialized : isPrintBossResponsesInitialized
    }

}]);


@RequestMapping(value="/billPaymentOuts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<BillPaymentOut> displayBillPaymentOutPage() {

    ...

    return lList;

}
```

Comment: How about `$http.delete`?

Comment: Maybe you can delete them one by one with their id by sending an $http.delete in a loop ?

Comment: Why are there so many methods shown and no indication of which request creates the problem? If it is a GET request chances are you are surpassing character limits which vary between browsers. Question is pretty vague